# How can I map www.mysite.com/page to page.mysite.com?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, dictionary

Let's assume I have a domain *www.mydomain.com* and a page on my domain called *cats*. You can access the page via *www.mydomain.com/cats*.
What should I do to redirect or somehow map *www.mydomain.com/cats* to *cats.mydomain.com*?

Answer (score 0):

you must create a subdomain from your domain administration panel of your provider, once created you must edit DNS register for you new subdomain and redirect the A/AAA domain to IP of you server.

Depends if you are using plesk or cpanel you must add the new subdomain to your suscription and set up the root folder for this subdomain.

I hope I helped a little!